# Не переходит по адресу slug

Tags: python, django, slug

я еще новичок в django и только пытаюсь в нём разбираться и тут возник вопрос.
Вроде указал правильно slug, адрес и поведение при переходе, но мне пишет, что не находит шаблон, который в принципе у меня не существует(basic/category_detail.html). Пытался создать этот шаблон(мало ли надо конкретно его создавать), но эффекта, как понимаете не дало. Если можно ответьте развернуто, что где как и почему. Так как заметил, тут умеют разжевать лучше любого руководства.

Сам код :

view.py

```
class SetsDetailView(DetailView):
model = Category
queryset = Category.objects.filter(slug='sets')
context_object_name = 'sets_detail.html'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', test_view, name='base'),
path('<str:ct_model>/<str:slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
path('<slug:slug>', SetsDetailView.as_view(), name='sets_detail')
```

]

templates/sets.html

```
<a href= {%  url "sets_detail" slug='sets' %} class="list-group-item">Cуши</a>
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Имя категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Написано же,что не найден шаблон

Comment: Зачем вы используете `context_object_name` и почему не стали использовать `template_name`?

Comment: @andreymal спасибо большое, помогли:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

""" Здравствуйте, я тоже учусь.Этот вопрос у меня решен с помощью
документации django3.1.Ссылка
-https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Не могу сказать на сколько правильно но все в соответствии с
документацией.Давайте по порядку.Мое понимание выглядит так , как я
опишу ниже.

Мы имеем модель"""

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Имя категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

""" Для просмотра объектов модели нужен список в котором указаны эти объекты и ссылка на просмотр деталей.   """

---

categori/urls.py

from .views import CategoriListView, CategoriDetailView

Список -
path('categori/', views.CategoriListView.as_view(), name='categori_list'),

Детали -
path('categori/slug:slug/', CategoriDetailView.as_view(),    name='categori_detail'),

Создайте 2 файла html путь -- templates /categori/categori_list.html
templates /categori/categori_detail.html

templates/имя приложения/имя страницы html

---

categori/views.py
"""Класс списка категорий"""

```
class CategoriListView(ListView): 
   
    model = Adres
    template_name = 'categori/categori_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'categorii' # слово 'categorii' - произвольное.Это слово         #                                   - название списка в шаблоне categori_list.html 
#                                     по которому вы будете проходить циклом 
#                                     for для получения значений. 
     
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)        
        return context

class CategoriDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Categori
    template_name = 'categori/categori_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'detali'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        return context
```

---

```
templates/categori/categori_list.html

<div>
    <p> Можно не указывать в views (context_object_name  = 'categorii')
         вместо categorii в этом шаблоне поставить object_list</p>


        {% for categ in categorii %}               

                    <h5 >Имя категории: {{ categ.name }}</h5>
                    
                    <a href="/categori/{{ categ.slug }}" >Ссылка</a>
                      <p>Ссылка работает но как сделать лучше пока не знаю</p>               
        
            {% endfor %}
</div>
```

---

```
templates/categori/categori_detail.html

<h2> Категория : {{ detali.name }}</h2>

<p>Слаг: {{ detali.slug }}</p>
```

---

Все.Код рабочий. Использую.